# mysql update column based on event

Tags: mysql, time, sql-update

I have a database table that contain data of different farming pratices during several years on several fields. Farmers entered there information based on the dates when a certain activity was done. A simplified example would look like this, where ID is an auto-increment value.

```
ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |
```

Now I would like to add a column called "Season" that contains only the year when a field was harvested but is automatically updated for all other activites between the last harvest and this harvest for individual fields. Note that harvest dates are different for different fields. In this example the output would ideally look like:

```
ID|Field|Date      |Activity  |Season
 1|A    |2012/08/01|Tillage   |2013
 2|A    |2012/08/24|Seeding   |2013
 3|A    |2013/03/05|Spraying  |2013
 4|A    |2013/03/05|Fertilizer|2013
 5|A    |2013/07/25|Harvest   |2013
 6|B    |2012/09/01|Tillage   |2013
 7|B    |2012/09/05|Seeding   |2013
 8|B    |2013/04/05|Spraying  |2013
 9|B    |2013/07/28|Harvest   |2013
10|B    |2010/08/24|Tillage   |2011
11|B    |2010/09/29|Seeding   |2011
12|B    |2011/05/01|Fertilizer|2011
13|B    |2011/07/12|Harvest   |2011
14|A    |2011/09/01|Seeding   |2012
15|A    |2011/10/10|Spraying  |2012
16|A    |2012/04/10|Fertilizer|2012
17|A    |2012/08/02|Harvest   |2012
```

How would I do that for the present data? Are triggers a good application for future data entry?

Comment: Do you really need to _store_ that in a new column? You could just as well query it at runtime or create a view which does it something like `SELECT Field, YEAR(MAX(Date)) AS Year FROM yourtable GROUP BY Field`

Comment: This would work, if harvest and seeding would be done in the same year, but seeding for example is done in fall 2011 while harvest is done in summer 2012. So I would prefer something that accounts for that

Comment: In addition I have multiple seasons for every field as shown in the example

Comment: I understand. I didn't thoroughly comprehend the issue.